# если поле ввода не в фокусе, скрыть кнопки "Прикрепить" и "Отправить"

Tags: javascript

Суть задачи: в профиле пользователя должна быть возможность разместить на стене запись. Необходимо, чтобы была форма для ввода - поле для ввода, кнопка "Прикрепить" и кнопка "Отправить". Но с одним нюансом, если поле ввода не в фокусе, они должны быть скрыты. Я это реализовал с помощью onfocus.

```js
text.onfocus = function() {
  $("#success").fadeIn(1);
};

text.onblur = function() {
  $("#success").fadeOut(1);
};
```

```css
#success {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-post">
  <form>
    <textarea name="text" id="text" class="login-forma" placeholder="Что у Вас нового?" rows="1"></textarea>
    <div class="addpost" id="success">
      <a href="">Прикрепить</a>
      <input type="submit" value="Рассказать" name="add_post" class="btn btn-success" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Проблема в том, что если нажимаешь на кнопку прикрепить, или отправить, то, очевидно же, текстовое поле теряет фокус и нажатие не срабатывает, а просто скрывает кнопки. Как сделать, чтобы они пропадали лишь при потере фокуса поля + потере фокуса самого блока с кнопками?

Comment: Не стоит оценивать сложность задач, которые вы не можете решить.

Comment: Пожалуй да, вы правы. Но. Хоть я в JS очень слаб, однако догадываюсь, что нужно всего-навсего условие добавить, но не могу его сформулировать правильно.

Comment: Если вы добавите остальную форму и код - быстрее получите решение. Нужно увидеть проблему вживую. А сейчас для этого нужно сделать много догадок и телодвижений.

Comment: @vp_arth Добавил

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Sultanov Shamil Хотелось бы именно по нажатию

Comment: @vp_arth Почему-то всё равно по нажатию на кнопки они просто скрываются... И ещё, по варианту Anton Shchyrov, я нажимаю на прикрепить, открывается окно выбора файла, но одновременно с этим опять же скрывается див с кнопками.

Comment: @vp_arth по нажатию на кнопки, они просто скрываются

Comment: @Дмитрий посмотри такой вариант, всё отрабатывает :D

Comment: @Дмитрий, лучше комментировать ответы под ответами

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, так - добавить обработчики всем элементам формы

```js
$("#post *").focus(
  function() {
    $("#success").fadeIn(1);
    console.log("focus");
  }).blur(function() {
  console.log("blur");
  $("#success").fadeOut(1);
});
```

```css
#success {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-post">
  <form id="post">
    <textarea name="text" id="text" class="login-forma" placeholder="Что у Вас нового?" rows="1"></textarea>
    <div class="addpost" id="success">
      <a href="">Прикрепить</a>
      <input type="submit" value="Рассказать" name="add_post" class="btn btn-success" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю, как вариант, добавить флаг нахождения курсора над элементами формы:

```js
(function () {
  // обработка флага
  var hoverButton = false;
  $('.form-ctrl').on('mouseover', function(){ hoverButton = true;});
  $('.form-ctrl').on('mouseleave', function(){ hoverButton = false;});
  
  function hide() {
    hoverButton = false;
    text.onblur();
  }
  $('#add_post').on('click', function add_post(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // не отправляем форму из сниппета
    console.log("Отправлено");
    hide();
  });
  $('#attach').on('click', function() {
    console.log("Прикреплено");
    hide();
  });

  text.onblur = function() {
    if (!hoverButton)
      $("#success").fadeOut(1);
  };
  text.onfocus = function() {
    $("#success").fadeIn(1);
  };
  
})();
```

```css
#success {
  display: none;
}

.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 30%!important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-post">
  <form>
    <textarea name="text" id="text" class="login-forma" placeholder="Что у Вас нового?" rows="1"></textarea>
    <div class="addpost" id="success">
      <a href="javascript:" id="attach" class="form-ctrl">Прикрепить</a>
      <input id="add_post" type="submit" value="Рассказать" name="add_post" class="btn btn-success form-ctrl" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: @Дмитрий, По нажатию форма выполняет своё действие(вывод в консоль) и элементы управления скрываются(за это отвечает вызов функции hide), приводя форму к первоначальному состоянию. Вы вправе изменить это поведение.

Answer (score 0):

Не проще ли реализовать этот же функционал, не используя собственно JS ?

Добавь в CSS и убери или закомментируй скрытие `#success` :

```css
#success {
  display: none;
}

#text:focus + #success  {
  display: block;
}
#success:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-post">
  <form>
    <textarea name="text" id="text" class="login-forma" placeholder="Что у Вас нового?" rows="1"></textarea>
    <div class="addpost" id="success">
      <a href="">Прикрепить</a>
      <input type="submit" value="Рассказать" name="add_post" class="btn btn-success" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```